# How do I append to a dictionary using a dynamic key?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My example document is shown like this:

```
{
    id:"some objid",
    name: "name",
    revision: "rev",
    data:{
         key1 : [
            {
                name: "some name",
                comment: "some comment"
            },
            {
                name: "some name2",
                comment: "some comment"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Where 'key1' would be my dynamic key. The query looks something like this:

```
var data={};
data[newKey]=arrayOfObjects;

collection.update({name:"name", revision:"rev"},{$set:{data}},{upsert:true}, function(err, data){
//code here...
}
```

I was thinking that doing the query this way would append data.newKey to the dictionary however it just overwrites the whole dictionary. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) to create the subdocument with the dynamic key, something like

```
var data = {};
data["data."+newKey] = arrayOfObjects;

collection.update(
    { name: "name" },
    { $set: data },
    { upsert: true },
    function (err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(data);
    }
)
```

Comment: Dang, I could have sworn I tried this already. It seems to be working now. Thanks for the help!